# Unexpected token Syntax error Node JS GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am following the tutorial located here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started. I am trying to use the JavaScript code and am getting this syntax error:

```
    import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! guide-graphql@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the guide-graphql@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I have tried other Node JS examples as well and am getting the same error. Below is the `package.json` as well. I am running `npm start` to execute. Any advice would be appreciated on fixing this syntax.

```
{
  "name": "guide-graphql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Apollo GraphQL server for Guide",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.3.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be unnecessary since you've specified type as module but you can try renaming all your files with the `.mjs` extension (eg. `app.mjs`)

Comment: I've fixed the error by upgrading the version of node.